# Postgres function ambiguous column reference

Tags: postgresql, function

Got two functions made from the same template :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rdxi(
    mydate date DEFAULT (
    (
    'now'::text)::date - '1 day'::interval))
RETURNS TABLE("Date" date, "Nom" character varying, "Capacité (TB)" numeric, "Utilisé (TB)" numeric, "Charge (%)" text, "Données protégées (TB)" numeric, "Ratio" numeric) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT "rDxi"."Date", "rDxi"."Nom", "rDxi"."Capacité réelle en TB", "rDxi"."Utilisé en TB", "rDxi"."Charge", "rDxi"."Données protégées en TB", "rDxi"."Ratio"
 from "rDxi" where "rDxi"."Date" = mydate;
END
$BODY$;
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."rPower-Chassis-Ram"(
    mydate date DEFAULT (
    (
    'now'::text)::date - '1 day'::interval))
RETURNS TABLE("Date" date, "Id" character varying, "Nom" character varying, "Cpu type" text, "Ram totale (GB)" numeric, "Ram libre (GB)" numeric, "Charge (%)" numeric) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Date", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Id", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Nom", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Type Cpu", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Ram Totale", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Ram_Libre",
"rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Charge"
 from "rPower-Chassis-Ram" where "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Date" = mydate;
END
$BODY$;
```

No problem when asking for the first one, but I've got the following error message when asking for the second one :

```
ERROR:  column reference "rPower-Chassis-Ram.Date" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Date", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Id...
               ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  SELECT "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Date", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Id", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Nom", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Type Cpu", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Ram Totale", "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Ram_Libre",
"rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Charge"
 from "rPower-Chassis-Ram" where "rPower-Chassis-Ram"."Date" = mydate
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "rPower-Chassis-Ram"(date) line 3 at RETURN QUERY
État SQL :42702
```

Don't know where to investigate, tried changing name of the function (replacing - by _), tried to rename with a common name with no specials char into, but no way...

Answer (score 0):

The name collision is between the funcrion parameter and the column name.

The easiest solution is to avoid the name collision, e.g. by calling the `OUT` parameter `p_date`.

Alternatively you can use a table alias:

```
SELECT t."Date"
FROM aschema."SillyTableName" AS t
...
```

Comment: Yes, but what about the working first function, with the same column name 'date' ?

Comment: There the function name (`rdxi`) is different from the table name (`"rDxi"`). Case matters.